# flask Indentation errors for returns

Tags: python, flask, indentation

I keep having indentation issues with my flask app.
Specifically when I try to declare a variable before a return statement.  Also when I try to use `session['logged_in] = True` before a return statement.

Tried searching for any indication that i am structuring this incorrectly, what am I missing?

```
from app import app
from flask import render_template, url_for, request, url_for, redirect, session
from form import NewUser

@app.route('/')
def home():
    return render_template('home.html')

@app.route('/logout')
def logout():
    session.pop('logged_in', None)
    redirect(url_for('home'))

@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    form = NewUser()

    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' and request.form['password'] != 'password':
            error = "uername/password incorrect"
            return render_template('login.html', form=form, error=error)
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return redirect(url_for('secretarea'))
    return render_template('login.html', form=form, error=error)


@app.route('/secretarea')
def secretarea():
    if session['logged_in'] = True:
        return "this area is a secret"
    else:
        error="please log in"
        return render_template('login.html', error=error)
```

The error I get is this

```
  File "runserver.py", line 2, in <module>
    from app import app
  File "/home/roman/flask/myblog/app/__init__.py", line 9, in <module>
    from app import views
  File "/home/roman/flask/myblog/app/views.py", line 21
    return render_template('login.html', form=form, error=error)
    ^
  IndentationError: unexpected indent
```

Comment: 2 things - 1. make sure you do not mix tabs and spaces. 2. You forgot a `return` statement on `logout` endpoint

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your login view  is not structured properly. In the last return line, you are trying to pass the 'error' variable which you defined inside the if condition. Also you don't need to return the login.html template twice. I would re-arrange the view as:

```
@app.route('/login', methods=['POST', 'GET'])
def login():
    form = NewUser()
    error='' # initialize the error variable outside the if loop
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if request.form['username'] != 'admin' and request.form['password'] != 'password':
            error = "uername/password incorrect"
        else:
            session['logged_in'] = True
            return redirect(url_for('secretarea'))

    # This line will execute if GET request OR the username/password checks fails
    return render_template('login.html', form=form, error=error)
```

Comment: Thank you for answering.  I dont have enough rep to give you an upvote yet but will circle back when I do, cheers!